# Pushing dataframe to postgres using sqlalchemy and psycogp2

Tags: python, python-2.7, postgresql

I am trying to write dataframes to postgres . For that DBAPI used is psycogp2.

```
localconn='postgresql+psycopg2://postgres/PSWD@localhost:5432/localPG'
localEng=engine.create_engine(localconn)
df.to_sql("DUMMY", localEng)
```

But its throwing error `(psycopg2.OperationalError) could not translate host name postgres to address: Name or service not known`

localPG is the database name.

Where I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The format you have written is wrong, use the following:

```
localEng = create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2://[user]:[pass]@[host]:[port]/[schema]', echo=False)
```

and of course, you should replace every parameter between the bracket with the equivalent database credentials.

Comment: Thanks a lot @rachid.  I searched a lot.. everywhere the format was same which I used.  Anyways it really helped.